# Should intermediate proxies recognize <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control">?

Tags: html, http, caching

Is the HTML tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store">
```

equivalent to the HTTP response header `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store`, especially from the perspective of intermediate proxies and caches (between the client and the server)?

Should an intermediate cache parse all the HTML-`<head>` section, looking for these types of headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, proxies should not have to read the document, and in general will not do so.